# Squats & Oats,Diet, and muscle mass

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, squats, weight-gain, muscle-gain

I've been wondering if I could do regular squats instead of squats with weights (because I have none & there's no gym near)
I want to build a bigger butt but I heard that it won't work if you don't have weights and proper diet & it could make your butt smaller instead ..well I have the diet plan just no weights.. Any suggestions.?

Comment: If your *only* goal is a bigger butt, you can get something heavy (anything really) and do hip thrusts and glute bridges.

Comment: you can try to use books as weights.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do one-legged stuff, as any weight added will have double effect.

Some good one-leg exercises for a bigger butt;

[Lunges](https://www.google.no/search?q=lunges&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDIQsARqFQoTCLfa79_w2MYCFQnDcgodK0sPoQ&biw=1689&bih=905)

[One leg bench squat](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/images/2012/one-leg-bench-squat.jpg)

You can add weight without proper weights. Fill a couple buckets with equal amount of water and hold one in each hand, for instance. Or get any ol' bar with some light weights. Such sets are usually very affordable. I'm talking 20lb bar, and some small metal plates. These are made for home use, and as such, are very small, but dense.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something else instead? Keep something heavy in your arms or put on a backpack an fill it with heavy stuff.

When you can do at most 12 reps*3 sets you are working out at a level where you will be adding muscle mass efficiently. More than that and you're mostly gaining endurance.

There are also harder versions of body weight squats you can do, like pistol squats, jump squats and box jumps.

High rep squats will not make your butt smaller, why would it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a calistenics leg workout. Studies have proven that hypertrophy (muscle growth) is the same when doing 30 reps or 10 reps. So just do things like squats, hip trusters and other leg exercise for 30 reps.